# How to update the varbinary value with null in an image field in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have uploaded an image and stored into image field in database, that image is stored as 0xFFD8FFE. When I am trying to update the above with null as getting an exception called:

> The datatypes image and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator

I want to change the above value to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it to null with an update statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
  SET MyFieldName = NULL
  WHERE MyPrimaryKey = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

update organisation set logo= null 
where logo **like** 0xFFD8FFE00010