# how to update the varbinary value with null in an image field in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the varbinary value(oXFFDFFEEEFFFF....) stored in an image field of sql server to null

Comment: And what is stopping you? What is the problem you are seeing with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585177/how-to-update-the-varbinary-value-with-null-in-an-image-field-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: i am getting an exception called 'The data types image and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ImageColumn = NULL WHERE Id = @Id
```

Comment: Than u for reply, but i have already tried and got above exception

Comment: @user377855: Please update your post and give more information.  Are you getting this error from SQL Server Management Studio, or is it in your application?  Please post your code as well.

Comment: i am getting this exception in sqlserver mgmt studio,my query is:update organisation set logo= null where logo=0xFFD8FFE00010.......

Comment: i am getting this exception in sqlserver mgmt studio,my query is:update organisation set logo= null where logo=0xFFD8FFE00010.......                 here organisation is tablename, logo is column of type image and  can i replace that value with null or with any other binary value

Comment: i think your problem is with your "where" condition. try to set it to the ID of the record instead of the logo value